# Dows mlflow support real-time metrics viewing

Tags: real-time, metrics

People use TensorBoard to view real-time update to the model metrics, is this feature also available with mlflow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with mlflow.  But with the comet_ml library you can watch during training the real-time updates.